# Получить html блока

Tags: php, javascript

На странице есть анкета с текстовыми полями, таблицами и прочим. Пользователь может добавлять поля динамически, т.е. нажимает на кнопочку и появляется еще одно текстовое поле куда он чего-нибудь записывает. После того как закончил - нажимает кнопку отправить.
Нужно все что он написал отправить на *email*. Конечно можно через `javascript` обратиться по очереди ко всем элементам, считать их значения, составить тело письма и отправить, но их достаточно много...
Можно ли получить полное содержимое блока где находится вся нужная информация?
Пробовал через `$("#moydiv").html()` - не помогает.

КОД:

```
<div id="app">
    <div>
        <div>
            <strong>
                <center>
                    Общие сведения об организации:
                </center>
            </strong>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div>
            Наименование организации:
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="text" name="" id="name_company" class="input_app">
        </div>
        <div>
            Наименование объекта информатизации (ОИ):
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="text" name="" id="name_oi" class="input_app">
        </div>
    <br><center><strong>Окна:</strong></center>
        </div>
        <div>
            <table>
                <colgroup>
                    <col width="250">
                    <col width="100">
                    <col width="100">
                    <col>
                    <col width="120">
                    <col width="120">
                </colgroup>
                <thead style="border: 1px solid;">
                    <tr>
                        <th rowspan="2" style="text-align: center;">
                            Номер окна
                        </th>
                        <th colspan="2" style="text-align: center;border: 1px solid;">Размеры (м)</th>
                        <th rowspan="2" style="text-align: center;border: 1px solid;">Материал</th>
                        <th rowspan="2" style="text-align: center;border: 1px solid;">Количество сегментов стекла</th>
                        <th rowspan="2" style="text-align: center;border: 1px solid;">Расстояние межд. стекл. (мм)</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th style="text-align: center;border: 1px solid;">Шир. (м)</th>
                        <th style="text-align: center;border: 1px solid;">Выс. (м)</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="okna">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 100px; border: 1px solid; padding: 5px;">
                            <input name="OKNO[]" type="text" class="form__input" placeholder="№">
                        </td>
                        <td style="width: 50px;border: 1px solid;padding: 5px;">
                            <input name="SHIR[]" type="text" class="form__input">
                        </td>
                        <td style="width: 50px;border: 1px solid;padding: 5px;">
                            <input name="VIS[]" type="text" class="form__input">
                        </td>
                        <td style="width: 100px;border: 1px solid;padding: 5px;">
                            <select name="MAT[]" style="height: 38px; width: 100%; border:none;">
                                <option value="пластик">пластик</option>
                                <option value="дерево">дерево</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                        <td style="width: 50px;border: 1px solid;padding: 5px;">
                            <input name="KOLO[]" type="text" class="form__input">
                        </td>
                        <td style="width: 50px;border: 1px solid;padding: 5px;">
                            <input name="ORASST[]" type="text" class="form__input">
                        </td>
                    </tr>


                </tbody>
            </table>
   <div style="margin-top: 10px">
        <input type="button" name="" value="Добавить" onclick="addotss()" class="mybutton">  // эта функция добавляет строчки в таблицу
    </div>
  <form action="index.php" method="post">
                    <!--<input type="submit" name="tutu" value="Добавить">-->
                    <input type="button" name="" value="отправить" onclick="sendmes()" class="mybutton">
                </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Приведите пример вашего кода. А вообще - делаете все поля в форме, чтобы и при добавлении поля - оно было добавлено в форму.  И при нажатии кнопки сабмитите форму через js.

Comment: Добавил код.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте всем тэгам `input` атрибут `name` и присвойте ему соответствующее значение:

```
<input type="text" name="email">
```

В php скрипте обработчика формы вы сможете получить доступ к значениям всех полей через глобальный массив `$_POST`. К примеру значение input'а, приведенного выше, можно получить так:

```
$email = $_POST['email'];
```

Там где поля добавляются пользователям динамически, в атрибут `name` добавляете имя с квадратными скобками:

```
<input type="text" name="arr[]">
```

И тогда на сервер придет массив значений этих полей.

Comment: Это более менее понятно, но не интересно... Интересно просто взять и отправить себе же на почту просто кусок страницы которую заполнил user... А бегать по всем элементам страницы и считывать их значения долго...

Comment: @Александр, тоесть неинтересно? А вы хотите как собрать значения всех инпутов со страницы?) Можно сделать цикл по всех инпутах на странице, собрать с них данные, записать в объект и выслать на сервер. Но если добавить атрибут name все это будет сделано автоматически за вас. ) Но если хочется писать велосипеды то ок)

Comment: мне просто казалось, что можно получить html блока вместе с значениями value тега input. Что-то типа $("body").html() или $("body").innerText. Ведь javascript видит все что есть на странице... Разве нельзя javascript'ом взять сразу все со значениями разом???